# Run pytest test case in thread isolation

Tags: python, django, multithreading, pytest

I want to test a function which uses thread_local variable i.e. `threading.local().setattr()` and `threading.local().getattr()`
When I run my single test case it passes since it is only test using the thread but when I run pytest in the project which runs all tests in the project, it looks like other test cases are reusing the same thread and my thread_local variable is getting overwritten.

Is there a simple way to keep my test case independent from other tests, either by running in a separate thread or locking thread while this test is running(less preferable solution, in this case, I'd rather delete this test case)

Comment: The best solution is to not use thread local variables, especially shared. Whenever I see anyone using thread local variables it is almost always a bad design.

Comment: @freakish it's a shared cross-team library that uses thread local, I need to ensure my code is using the library correctly.

Comment: If a library uses a thread local variable inside, why does it matter to you? It should be an implementation detail. What you are interested in is API only, not implementation details. Unless the behaviour depends on the thread the function runs on. In such a case you have a very poorly designed lib and a big problem.

Comment: @freakish, I'll add more context here. the common library I'm referring to is a Django middleware, which sets values from the HTTP request header to `thread_local` variable. My production code later uses this `thread_local` variable and sends it to the logger. The test I'm adding is to verify that I receive the correct value is sent to the logger which I sent in the API request from test.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way could be create new process to test threading (or other) things isolated.

Something like this:

```py
def test_something():
    from multiprocessing import Process
    
    def process_main():
        # ... test threading things here

    p = Process(target=process_main)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    assert p.exitcode == 0
```

Do not mix threads and creating processes.
There should exist only one thread (the main thread) when starting (forking) a new process.